# Vuejs : Not able to get the key-value pair of an object in V-html

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have custom-preset.js file with the following code.I'am using this get a dynamic value for background color for the button.

```
var customPresets;
export default customPresets = color => (
    {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "custom",
    "html": `<button id='changecolor' style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: ${color}; border-color: rgb(158, 50, 168);'>Accept</button>`
    }
)
```

I want to print the html returned from this js in a vue file  In the vue file I have the following code:

```
<b-form-radio-group>
   <b-form-radio v-for="customPreset in customPresets">
      <div v-html="customPreset.html"></div>  /// not getting this printed 
   </b-form-radio>
</b-form-radio-group>



import customPresets from './custom-preset';

 mounted () {
   console.log(customPresets);  /// I'am getting the output of this correctly
 }
```

[image]

Neither am I able to print console.log(customPresets.id) - getting undefined. I want to access the html ( key: value pairs ) in the vue file

Comment: `customPresets` is a function that will need to be invoked with one `color` argument. You will need to call/invoke the function so that it returns an object, for example: `<b-form-radio v-for="customPreset in customPresets('blue')">`

Comment: Yea , I corrected that. But stll console.log(customPresets.html); or v-html="customPreset.html" is not working. I needed that to work

Comment: You need to call the method first and then access `.html` prop out of it, like I have done in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-river-trtpf?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `customPresets()` returns an object you don't need to loop here. You can simply pass a color name like `green`, etc to the `customPresets()` and then access `html` property value like:

```
<b-form-radio>
   <div v-html="customPresets('green').html"></div>
</b-form-radio>
```

Comment: Actually , I wanted to pass an array of objects. So I can Loop it right ?